# how to use stereo_image_proc.launch

Tags: stere-image-proc, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone,when i roslaunch stereo_image_proc stereo_image_proc.

launch.... logging to /home/administrator/.ros/log/382adbce-609e-11e3-acbd-e89a8ff90e16/roslaunch-ubuntu-11072.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

arg 'manager' is not defined.

Arg xml is

Where is the problem。

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108291/how-to-use-stereo_image_proc.launch/) by [luo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4815/luo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-12-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Edmodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/14091/edmodi/) on 2016-05-31**:
Hi, I have the same problem. Do you resolve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `stereo_image_proc.launch` file must be included in another launch file where `manager` is defined and a nodelet manager is started. You'll need provide a globally qualified manager name so that all nodelets get added to the same manager, which basically means adding a leading `/` to the name. Be careful with the namespaces.

For example, you could create a launch file named `my_rig.launch`:

```
<launch>

  <!-- Start a nodelet manager; the name must be unqualified here -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="pipeline" args="manager" />

  <!-- Include the stereo_image_proc.launch file and pass in a qualified manager name -->
  <include file="$(find stereo_image_proc)/launch/stereo_image_proc.launch" ns="stereo">
    <arg name="manager" value="/pipeline" />
  </include>

</launch>
```

This only works if your left and right image topics are named `/stereo/left/image_raw` and `/stereo/right/image_raw`, and the images are synchronized and have timestamps that match exactly. If your timestamps don't match exactly you'll need to use approximate sync, which means modifying `stereo_image_proc.launch` (see the TODO in the file), or creating your own stereo launch file with the correct parameters.

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2018-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1